# How to disable infowindow from registered places from map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi am new to google maps. I have used gmaps jquery plugin for displaying map. In that i have my own markers and polylines for some locations,and displaying the infowindow when clicking on those markers. But some areas like crissy field i didn't define any marker or polyline but when clicking on it am getting infowindow by default. How to remove that infowindow pls help.

Comment: are you using the jquery for  google maps, try to post the code to get the help

Comment: yeah....am displaying map using jquery plugin.

Comment: so there (areas like crissy field) where you are clicking are you having the markers in that region where you don't want the info window

Comment: we dont have any markers and polylines. There is one symbol like small tree,when clicking on it the infowindow will open and displaying the details. you can see this in normal google map also.

Comment: Then you can simply see the handler of that tree and use the infowindow.close() to close the infowindow there :D

Comment: so if you post the code it will be simple to check the handler and close the infowindow

Comment: if you are unable to find the exact handler you can see the answer below which I have given :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to prevent those infowindows from opening is to turn off the POIs using [styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), something like:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: HI actually the above styling is useful for disable the POI. But is there any possibility to display the POIs with clicking disabled..?? @geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

There is a close() function for InfoWindows. Just keep track of the last opened window, and call the close function on it when a new window is created.

This demo(http://www.lootogo.com/googlemapsapi3/markerPlugin.html) has the functionality you're looking for. I found it in the Maps API V3 demo gallery.

Comment: He is talking about the clickable "poi" on the map tiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stylesArray = [
  {
    featureType: '',
    elementType: '',
    stylers: [
      {hue: ''},
      {saturation: ''},
      {lightness: ''},
      // etc...
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: '',
    // etc...
  }
]
```

you can change its features like hide the feature completely as below

```
stylers: [
  { visibility: "off" }
]
```

you can refer link about the poi as below if you are using the version3

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to prevent this behavior is to call the `stop()` method on a click event attached to the Map instance.

```
map.addListener("click", e => e.stop());
```