# How do you reference a system info-window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, window, maps

When you click on some POI on the Google map an system built-in info window will be opened by the map engine.
How do you get a reference to that window (I want to close it on the next click on the map).

Comment: You can't reference those.

Comment: Such a nice commentless down-vote and a close-vote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Work with native infoWindows of interesting places in google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202034/work-with-native-infowindows-of-interesting-places-in-google-maps-api/21884991#21884991)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable infowindow from registered places from map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117218/how-to-disable-infowindow-from-registered-places-from-map/13117452#13117452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some similar questions before:

- [How to get a click event when a user clicks a (business) place on the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234106/how-to-get-a-click-event-when-a-user-clicks-a-business-place-on-the-map/24234818#24234818)
- [click event listener on styled map icons and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels/21488643#21488643)

The approach there is to override a method of the Infowindow-prototype to get a reference, adapted code:

```
//run this after loading the maps-api

(function(){
  var fx = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent;

  //override the built-in setContent-method
  google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent = function () {

    //this property isn't documented, but as it seems
    //it's only defined for InfoWindows opened on POI's
    if (this.logAsInternal) {
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this, 'map_changed',function () {
        var map = this.getMap(),that=this;
        //attach the click-handler when the infowindow opens
        if (map) {
          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(){that.close();});
        }
      });
    }
  //call the original setContent-method
  fx.apply(this, arguments);
  };})();
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Q7Gbb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Q7Gbb/)

Answer (score 3):

*This is issue #4797 tracked in the Google Maps API issue tracker, and was recently fixed, and available in version 3.26.*

Starting with version 3.26 you should listen to the "click" event on the Map object. If the user clicks on a POI a IconMouseEvent is raised. This class extends the Regular MouseEvent and contains a property called placeId. So you can check if the event object has defined placeId. The placeId field contains of course a Place Id, that you can use with Places API to get more info on the icon that was clicked.

I prepared a small demo: http://jsbin.com/parapex/10/edit?html,output

In short your map "click" event handler should look like this:

```
// This is the click event handler
var handleClick = function(event) {
// If the event has a placeId, use it.
  if (event.placeId) {
    // Calling e.stop() on the event prevents the default info window
    // from showing.
    // If you call stop here when there is no placeId you will prevent
    // some other map click event handlers from receiving the event.
    event.stop();
    // do something with event.placeId here. Like calling places service
  }
};
```